# Visual Studio: Rescource.ID. dont find my Button

Tags: android, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a button that brings me to a new page. Anything else works, just the `Resource.ID` don't find the ID of the button. In an other program, it worked normally but I don't know what I did wrong. This is my button:

```
<Button
    android:text="Next Page"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:background="#fff55858"
    android:drawableLeft= "@drawable/abc_ic_star_black_36dp"/>
```

and thats my cs page:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    var btn_nextPage = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.ID.Button1);
    btn_nextPage.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(layout1));
        StartActivity(nextActivity);
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using Kotlin.

While using kotlin, you don't have to create an instance of any view in order to use that. You can directly use the `resource id`, like so:

```
// If, 'Button1' is the id of your Button, then use this:
Button1.Click += (s, e) => {
    Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(layout1));
    StartActivity(nextActivity);
};
```

This will work.